# Upload product on Prestashop store using API with payload in JSON

Tags: json, prestashop, product

I am trying to create a product on Prestashop and using JSON formatted payload but getting error 500.
It is not supporting the JSON formatted payload.
Is there any way to upload the products using JSON payload?  I used the below structure in the postman:

```
url = {base_url} + api/products     
payload = json.dumps({ "product": { "name": "Sample Product", "price": "19.99", "description": "This is a sample product description.", "category": "1" } })  
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth key }     
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

But I got the error 500 and response as:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <errors> <error> <code><![CDATA[3]]></code> <message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found (/var/www/html/presta/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1541)]]></message> </error> <error> <code><![CDATA[3]]></code> <message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): {"product": {"name": "Sample Product", "price": "19.99", "description": "This is (/var/www/html/presta/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1541)]]></message> </error> <error> <code><![CDATA[3]]></code> <message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ (/var/www/html/presta/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1541)]]></message> </error> <error> <code><![CDATA[127]]></code> <message><![CDATA[XML error : String could not be parsed as XML XML length : 130 Original XML : {"product": {"name": "Sample Product", "price": "19.99", "description": "This is a sample product description.", "category": "1"}}]]></message> </error> </errors> </prestashop>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can try to transform your JSON to XML structure, although I've never tried that approach.

You can also find example Postman collections here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/webservice-postman-examples